# mysql view error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, view

I have an sql query like this, its giving a syntax error but I couldn't find what it was:

```
CREATE VIEW 
    vw_hs_hr_wf_main_data AS 
        select mo.wfmod_id, 
            mo.wfmod_name, 
            mo.wfmod_view_name, 
            ty.wftype_code,
            ty.wftype_description, 
            ty.wftype_table_name, 
            ty.wftype_view_name,
            ma.wfmain_id, 
            ma.wfmain_sequence,
            CASE
                WHEN ap.wf_main_app_employee IS NULL
                    THEN ma.wfmain_approving_emp_number
                ELSE ap.wf_main_app_employee
            END  CASE AS wfmain_approving_emp_number,
            ma.wfmain_flow_id,
            ty.wftype_update_field, 
            ty.wftype_assembly,
            ty.wftype_assembly_class, 
            ma.wfmain_previous_id,
            ty.wftype_cancelmain_field, 
            ma.wfmain_application_date,
            ty.wftype_cancelstatus_field, 
            ty.wftype_appmain_field,
            ty.wftype_bulk_app_flg, 
            ty.wftype_sort_field_name
        FROM hs_hr_wf_module mo INNER JOIN hs_hr_wf_type ty
            ON mo.wfmod_id = ty.wfmod_id
        INNER JOIN hs_hr_wf_main ma 
            ON ty.wftype_code = ma.wftype_code
        LEFT JOIN hs_hr_wf_main_app_person ap
            ON ma.wfmain_id = ap.wfmain_id
                AND ma.wfmain_sequence = ap.wfmain_sequence
        WHERE (ma.wfmain_iscomplete_flg = 0);
```

The error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE AS wfmain_approving_emp_number, ma.wfmain_flow_id, ty.wftype_update_fiel' at line 11

Comment: It might be helpful to include the specific error message as well.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE AS wfmain_approving_emp_number, ma.wfmain_flow_id, ty.wftype_update_fiel' at line 11

here my error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `END CASE` to close the `CASE`, just `END`:

```
END AS wfmain_approving_emp_number,
```

A better choice in your case would be a [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) call:

```
COALESCE(ap.wf_main_app_employee, ma.wfmain_approving_emp_number)
AS wfmain_approving_emp_number
```

Comment: hi small problem. i can excute view when retrive data my wfmain_approving_emp_number field data always append the 3 to font of actual data example emp number shoud be 8 but its dispaly as 38

Comment: @Roshan: That doesn't make any sense, do you have any threes anywhere in your SQL or data? BTW, I updated my answer with a simpler option than your CASE statement.

Comment: its a phpmyadmin bug mysql commandline shows correct thanks sorry for distrub

Comment: @Roshan: No worries. You might want to go with the COALESCE approach anyway, I think it is clearer than the CASE and I prefer to go with the simplest possible solution (and the usually puts the SQL CASE at the bottom of the list).